# SynEdit for Firemonkey?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, synedit

Is there a synedit package that works with firemonkey (or someone working on it) ?

From what I can gather there was a VGScene port earlier (see: [this site](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=58470)), but it seems to been removed.

Also see [this site](http://ksdev.blogspot.com/2010/08/synedit-for-vgscene.html):

Comment: The `vg_synedit.pas` file can be found here http://www.ksdev.com/mplfiles/

Comment: Good find. But I was hoping for something a bit more complete. In general I think most of the display/scroll stuff would have to be rewritten. Something as simple as the scrollbars wont work under firemonkey - they would have to be replaced with FM's own versions. But the bulk of the text processing engine could be salvaged.

Comment: I'm not sure about salvaging the text processing: Delphi's SynEdit is based on Windows text functions, these would have to be replaced for cross-platform use, and FireMonkey text support is quite limited/buggy.
A better start might be from the Lazarus fork of SynEdit, which is cross-platform already (but built against the LCL...), and more advanced on many aspects than the SourceForge (Delphi) version (cf. http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/SynEdit)

Comment: What would be nice is to abstract the code which deals with text handling from the display functionality. Some overlapping will occur, especially when dealing with fontmetrics, scale and row drawing - but it would be sad if synEdit did not make it over. Lazarus solved it my having a very heavy emulation layer. Even messages are emulated by lazarus. Perhaps a clean rewrite is the only way. The code is to close to the layout/drawing/scrolling code which is extremely windows centric :(

Comment: Lazarus also invested in synedit heavily wrt folding and scaling to large filesizes. Martin Fr. is the main synedit guy atm

Answer (score 3):

There most likely is not (at the moment):

From the [homepage](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/synedit/index.php?title=SynEdit_Home_Page):

`It is a pure-VCL/CLX control, meaning it is not a wrapper for Microsoft Windows 
    controls and so no run-time library is required.`

CLX or Component Library for Cross Platform is the cross-platform equivalent of the VCL - Borland's widget library.

[From Nakeymonkey - native controls for firemonkey](http://members.adug.org.au/2012/07/28/nakeymonkey-native-controls-for-firemonkey-interview-with-jason-southwell/)

`With the VCL, Borland never had to worry about all of this because they just wrote a wrapper around the Windows API Rich Edit control. So why didn’t Embarcadero do the same thing with Firemonkey? Because Firemonkey also needs to compile for OS X and the Windows API Rich Edit control doesn’t exist there.`

Links:

- [Embarcadero Delphi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarcadero_Delphi)
- [Qt.pas pascal bindings for QT](http://freeclx.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/freeclx/freeclx/clx/Qt.pas?revision=1.4&view=markup)